# How to read all property keys configured using <context:property-placeholder>

Tags: spring

I wonder if it'd be possible to read all the key read from a properties file without resorting to reading the properties file itself. I have the placeholder configured like so

```
<context:property-placeholder
    system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"
    ignore-resource-not-found="true"
    location="classpath:/defaults.properties, file:${config.location:/etc/default/example.properties}" />
```

which sorts out pretty much every case that I need. Now I'd like to have a configuration overview page where I can verify if all the settings are properly configured without resorting to manually `@Value` injecting all the values into some `@Controller` and passing them to a view using `ModelAndView`.

Any ideas how to approach this or if it is even possible with the property-placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

`PropertyPlaceHolderConfigure` don't expose his properties but you can get the locations from the BeanDefinition and load thems with the same result.

```
BeanDefinition bd = configurableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory().getBeanDefinition("org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0");
    String[] locations = (String[]) bd.getPropertyValues().getPropertyValue("locations").getValue();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    for (String loc : locations) {
        props.putAll(PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(configurableApplicationContext.getResource(loc)));
    }
```